# view state in usercontrols

Tags: asp.net

Is it necessary to reload the viewstate of usercontrols during postback? I want to know in which case viewstate is set by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it's not necessary that everytime view state of a usercontrol or webcontrol will be set.
it can be controled during page cycle if `viewstate` properties  of a control set `=false` then it will not set while page is postback. autopostback.

you can also control viewstate properties of a usercontrol and webcontrol in pre_int stage of life cycle.  you can also `off tracing of view state in pre_int stage of life cycle`.
for more information [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: not necessary to set you viewstate properties it's automatically set for each control....by default

Comment: it's automatically set for each control